# Wine 1.6 USB Mouse Detection

Tags: drivers, wine, mouse, configure

I have a Perixx MX3000 mouse with 5 fully customizable profiles with different speeds, colors, and button binding. The problem is, its software is not made for Linux based operating systems, so I installed it in Wine (1.6). When I tried to launch the software to configure my mouse, it tells me that the mouse is not detected.

The mouse is still using the profile I set on Windows perfectly because the ctrl+C, ctrl+P, volume up, volume down, and show desktop buttons work perfectly. How can I make the software detect my mouse? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the relevant line for your mouse in the output of `lsusb`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the configuration software in Wine doesn't help, because it expects the Windows hardware drivers to be present. You will need to find working Linux drivers for your device.

Generally speaking, anything that involves direct hardware or driver access doesn't work in Wine.

Comment: Damn... Well could I do it via VirtualBox or would I need to go into my Windows partition?

Comment: Afaik some virtual machine environments support USB pass-through to the guest system, if the device isn't used by the host system. If you can configure your mouse through a VM at all, you won't be able to use the mouse in Linux at the same time.

Comment: The mouse has its own memory that stores its profiles.

Comment: Apparently that's what [someone on Reddit](//www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/2czysq/linux_software_for_logitech_unifying_receiver/cjl1zn0) did. It would be good, if you try it and write about your experience here in the form of an answer.